# Make a webpage that prevents to be stored on browser history

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, google-chrome, browser

For security reasons:

How to prevent a webpage link being stored on the history?

Additionally, how to prevent most of caching from the given link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't have a specific answer for you, I think you might find this article quite helpful: http://css-tricks.com/website-escape/ The use case described there is a site for helping victims of domestic abuse. Looking in the comments, you'll see many tips that others have found for hiding traces of visits to the site, etc. In terms of preventing a site from entering browser history, I don't know of a good way to do that, but perhaps the best choice is user education about various privacy modes that the browsers themselves offer (i.e. Chrome's private browsing or the similar feature in Safari).